# Skip over array elements only if the same key/value pair in other rows are also 0 in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, foreach

[Codepad Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9Fxhi4)

I 'm trying to create a comparison table from an array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Sony X852 
                       [4G] => 1 
                       [Backlighting] => 0 
                     ) 
        [1] => Array ( [name] => Nokia 12hb 
                       [4G] => 0 // have trouble with this element
                       [Backlighting] => 0 
                     ) 
        [2] => Array ( [name] => Asus 23yh 
                       [4G] => 1 
                       [Backlighting] => 0
                     ) 
      )

$table = "";
$table .= "<table><tbody>"; 
foreach($array as $key=>$val)
{
  $table .= "<tr>";

  foreach($val as $k=>$v)
  {
    if($k == "name")
    {
        $table .= "<td>$v</td>";
    }   
    else if($v > 0)
    {
        $table .= "<td>$k</td><td>$v</td>";
    }   
  } 
  $table .= "</tr>";  
}
$table .= "</tbody></table>";
print $table;
```

Here's my expected result:

```
   <table>
     <tbody>
         <tr><td>Sony X852</td><td>4G</td><td>1</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Nokia 12hb</td><td>4G</td><td>0</td></tr> // don't skip the 4G td for this phone
        <tr><td>Asus 23yh</td><td>4G</td><td>1</td></tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

But the output I'm getting from the code above is this:

```
   <table>
     <tbody>
         <tr><td>Sony X852</td><td>4G</td><td>1</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Nokia 12hb</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Asus 23yh</td><td>4G</td><td>1</td></tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

`1` and `0` here indicate whether a product has that feature. How can I skip over an element only if the same key/value pairs in the other rows are `0`? For example, all of the three products don't have  `Backlighting` features, so I use `if($v > 0)` to exclude the whole row of `Backlighting`, but I want  to keep any `0` element like Nokia 12hb's 4G because the other phones contain that feature.

Comment: I would suggest pretty much what Nicolas is suggesting. Put the data into another format where the feature is the key and is an array of values from all the products. Then as you go over each feature, you can check `if(count($features[$feature]) == count($products) && array_sum($features[$feature]) > 0) {...`. This will check that each feature exists on all phones (the column does exist) and will tell you if there is at least one with a 1.

Comment: Before printing anything, you need to loop over all the elements, and find the features that have non-zero values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding from the comment from @Barmar

```
$features = array();
foreach ($array as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != 'name' && $value > 0) {
            $features[] = $key;
        }
    }
}
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $table .= "<tr><td>{$row['name']}</td>";
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != 'name' && in_array($key, $features)) {
            $table .= "<td>{$key}</td><td>{$value}</td>";
        }
    }
    $table .= "</tr>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First make a list of all the features that have non-zero in some element:

```
$features = array('name' => true);
foreach ($array as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $feature => $val) {
        if (!isset($features[$feature]) && $val > 0) {
            $features[$feature] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use this in your output loop:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$val)
{
  $table .= "<tr>";

  foreach($val as $k=>$v)
  {
    if($k == "name")
    {
        $table .= "<td>$v</td>";
    }   
    elseif(isset($features[$k]))
    {
        $table .= "<td>$k</td><td>$v</td>";
    }   
  } 
  $table .= "</tr>";  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears simple.  The value for `$v` is never greater than zero in the second `Nokia` array!  So..your `else if($v > 0){..` never fires!

The solution here would be to check for `$v==0 || $v < 0`, then print the desired output as well.  Right now you aren't doing that so your output ignores when `$v` is zero or negative.